# Macro loop to pull data from sheet to sheet stopping when no data resent and not entering 0

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

I am trying to get the data from rows G,H, and I from row 15 down (stopping when there is no data present)from "order sheet", to be pasted in a sheet called “Data” in columns M,Q and R from row 8 down.

I have tried recording a macro, however as this data changes from day to day, my recorded macro stays the same and I don’t have the know how to place an IF formula in macro to stop it when there is no data in origin cell. One day the data will be from row 15 to 50 in the order sheet and the next 15 to 71 (always starts at 15). When I do the macro for say 200 rows so it does cover all rows no matter how many rows it may be, itll then places a zero in the data sheet when nothing present in order sheet cell. What I would like is for it to leave blank if there is no number in the order sheet cell.

e.g. 
“Order sheet” column paste to “Data sheet” (starting from row 15 down on order sheet and row 8 down on data sheet)
G   to  M /
H   to  Q /
I   to  R

e.g.
G15 to  M8 /
H16     to  Q9 /
I17 to  R10

See the basic recorder macro as an idea.

Thanks in advance

```
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15
Range("M8").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Order Sheet'!R[7]C[-6]"
Range("M8").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M8:M159"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("M8:M159").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-135
Range("Q8").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Order Sheet'!R[7]C[-9]"
Range("Q8").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q8:Q159"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("Q8:Q159").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-132
Range("R8").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Order Sheet'!R[7]C[-9]"
Range("R8").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("R8:R159"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("R8:R159").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-123
Range("I3").Select
```

Comment: You don't need the scrolls as you're setting by reference, also don't use select, so `range("R8").formulaR1C1=` for example.  You need to look at `range("R1000000").end(xlUp).Row` to define for your data

Comment: Do you want to copy the values (one time) or do you want to place references that update when the original cells are updated?

Comment: Hi @arcadeprecinct I would like them to copy one time so I can use that data in the new sheet. Once I get the new data the following day I plan to simple run the macro again to update the data sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to copy all values from `G15` downwards to `M8` downwards

```
Dim sourceSht As Worksheet 'sheet you want to copy from 
Dim targetSht As Worksheet 'sheet you want to copy too
Dim sourceRng As Range 'what you want to copy
Dim targetRng As Range 'where you want to copy to
Dim lastRow As Long 'the last row that holds data

Set sourceSht = Sheets("Order Sheet")
Set targetSht = Sheets("Data")

With sourceSht
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count,7).End(xlUp).Row '7 is the column number
End With

Set sourceRng = sourceSht.Range("G15:G" & lastRow)
Set targetRng = targetSht.Range("M8").Resize(sourceRng.Rows.Count, 1) ' Range("M8:M"& lastRow - 7) would also be possible
targetRng.Value = sourceRng.Value
```

You might want to introduce variables to hold the column indices and row numbers (like 15 and 8). You could also have the ranges contain more than one column to copy more data at once.

Comment: Hi @arcadeprecinct Thank you for the above and for the 'info as to what it references, this helps my understand and knowledge a lot. I have tried to run the macro but get an error with the line below;
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp) '7 is the column number - it is highlighted in yellow.

Comment: @Bradley I forgot a `.Row` when calculating the `lastRow`, should work now. Without `.Row` it's the cell itself and not its row index

Comment: Thank you @arcadeprecinct works great. in order to populate columns Q and R in the same way I have copied and edited the last two lines and works great. appreciate the help!